# Поиск по конкретной колонке DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Для составления таблиц использую [datatables.net](https://datatables.net). Все работает корректно, но никак не могу подключить дополнительный поиск по колонке, как показано по данной ссылке [datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html), хотя все делаю вроде бы верно. В чем может быть дело?

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><b>Наименование</b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b>Номер документа</b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b>Формат</b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b>Подлинник</b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b>Дубликат</b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b>Применяемость</b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b>Для отметок</b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b>Литера</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Инвентарный номер</b></td>
            <td><b>Дата поступления</b></td>
            <td><b>Инвентарный номер</b></td>
            <td><b>Дата поступления</b></td>
            <td><b>Обозначение</b></td>
            <td><b>Шифр индекса изделия</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><b>Наименование</b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b>Номер документа</b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b>Формат</b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b>Подлинник</b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b>Дубликат</b></td>
            <td colspan="2"><b>Применяемость</b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b>Для отметок</b></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><b>Литера</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Инвентарный номер</b></td>
            <td><b>Дата поступления</b></td>
            <td><b>Инвентарный номер</b></td>
            <td><b>Дата поступления</b></td>
            <td><b>Обозначение</b></td>
            <td><b>Шифр индекса изделия</b></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $j=0;
    while ($j<$i)
    {
        echo " <tr>
            <td>$DocumentName[$j]</td>
            <td>$DocumentNumber[$j]</td>
            <td>$DocumnetFormat[$j]</td>
            <td>$OriginalInventoryNumber[$j]</td>
            <td>$OriginalDataSupplay[$j]</td>
            <td>$DuplicationInventoryNumber[$j]</td>
            <td>$DuplicationDataSupplay[$j]</td>
            <td>$DesignationApplicability[$j]</td>
            <td>$CypherApplicability[$j]</td>
            <td>$ForMarks[$j]</td>
            <td>$Letter[$j]</td>
        </tr>"; 
        $j++;
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';    
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#table_id tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    });

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            // Apply the search
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Прежде всего, что это за пляски `$j=0; while ($j<$i)`? И почему данные в разных переменных? что-то не корректно получается. А насчет фильтров - добавьте [минимальный работающий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @InDevX Это я скриптом запрашиваю данные из базы данных и записываю в массивы и потом в цикле вывожу их

Comment: @InDevX Вообщем я нашел, в чем была проблема, у меня заголовки опредлены тегами <td>, а нужно <th>